# How to execute JS function outside jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function (){    
$( "#example").example({
select: function ( event, ui){
name(id);
}
)};
//now is started non jquery function
function name (id){
    document.getElementById(id);
}
});
```

So my question is - how to execute function outside the jQuery statement - in the place where is function(id), not in the jquery code, for example in the end of the script.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear and your code has errors, what is `select: { function(id)}`??

Comment: Do you want to substitute jQuery native function with your custom one? Is that what you're trying to do? Also I second gideon comment - your code has syntax errors and it's not clear what're you asking about.

Comment: I'm not quite sure we can answer your question as your syntax is completely wrong. Perhaps you can edit and clarify a bit? To start, your jQuery doesn't look right to me (maybe it's just me) and your JavaScript function doesn't have a function name.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript.

Comment: My suggestion is to go to http://w3schools.com and try some of their Try it Yourself examples. W3SChools isn't the most correct resource, but it's great for beginners who are just getting started.

Comment: I write for fast, to show my idea, not syntax. It's only idea guys. Not substitute, but I want to function be done not in place where is select: becouse if I do that as you see, my code doesn't work

Comment: I suppose you're defining a `select` event handler of some jQuery plugin. Is that the case? can you post your complete jQuery code?

Comment: By the way, in order to call a function you have to call it with just the function name eg: `name('3')` not as `function name('3')`

Answer (score 3):

look at this page: http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/

under 'Usage' you find the answere

Comment: So I have to write my own plugin? Is it only one solution?

Comment: I was the opinion that you are writing your own jQuery-Plugin... so what are you doing?

Comment: you updated your source example, but the comment below is not fitting.

Answer (score 3):

To put it simple - you can't do that. Or to be more specific you may not get desired results if you try to access any internal variables defined inside jQuery code.

You can't put your custom function in context of other object, and certainly you can't use your custom function and replace some inner function of yet another function in jQuery (or any other piece of code for that matter).

Comment: But my own function is in jQuery code.

Comment: From what I see in code you've posted - **call** of your function `name()` is inside jQuery code, not its declaration. So either I don't get it or you can't properly explain what your problem is. Perhaps switching to polish language might help here ;)

Comment: Muszę wywołać funkcję, tak żeby się ona wykonała tam gdzie jest `function name ()`.

Comment: Wyobraź sobie że masz zmieniające się karty. I masz np. jakiegoś diva. selectem, ustawiasz dla zmiennej id, wartość hrefa - czyli url. Potem masz funkcję która obrabia tego diva - div się zmienia po zmieniniu karty(przypisana wcześniej wartość hrefa do id). Jeśli tą funkcję obrabiającą wstawię w selecti, to mi nie działa zmienianie się kart. Jeśli tą funkcję wywołam za jQuery to wywoła się tylko raz, bo nie mam eventu przypisanego, ale widać że działa.

Comment: No ale chodzi o to, ze zmienna "id" ktora przekazujesz do funkcji name z Twojego przykladu, musi byc zdefiniowana i dostepna z punktu widzenia kodu w funkcji `select...`. Nawet zakladajac ze jest zdefiniowana, to nazwa "id" jest tak popularna, ze prawdopodobnie jest gdzies przedefiniowana w kodzie samego jQuery. Zainstaluj sobie firebug-a (rozszerzenie do firefoxa) i sprawdz jaki komunikat bledu dostajesz. To pomoze zdiagnozowac "o co kaman"

Comment: Jest, słuchaj, id to tylko obrazowo, tak naprawdę jest id_tabs. Jest zdefiniowane. I to normalnie działa, jeśli wywołam tak jak zwykłą funkcję ale pod całym kodem, przed samą deklaracją funkcji :) ok, w domu mam, robię to w szkole, a tam nie mam jak zainstalować więc jak wrócę do domu to zerknę. Można się jakoś skontaktować na stackoverflow z Tobą, i czy chciałbyś mi może pomóc? Może mail czy coś. Po przepisaniu maila usuniesz post po tym jak potwierdzę że przepisałem.

Comment: E-mail jest w moim profilu http://stackoverflow.com/users/909376/wtk

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that "jQuery code" *is* JavaScript, so in terms of language syntax there is no difference in how you define or call functions.

Your question is not very clear, but in a general sense if you have a "plain" JavaScript, non-jQuery function declared:

```
function name(id){
   document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Then you call it as:

```
name("someid");
// or
name(id); // assuming id is defined somewhere
```

If the function declaration is in the global scope then you can call `name()` from anywhere in your code.

So you can call it from within some jQuery stuff:

```
$("selector").jQueryMethodOfSomeKind(function() {
   name("someid");
});
```

Or in the example from your question which is a code-fragment that won't work on its own but presumably is the end of some sort of object literal, to call the `name()` function you need to drop the word `function` from in front of it like this:

```
   //some jquery code  
   select: function ( event, ui){
      name(id)
   }
});
```

Where `id` would need to be defined somewhere within the scope where the jQuery code is running.

Comment: Yes but if I do that my code doesn't work as I want. You see that I've got an `select:`, so i use it for selecting items - in this case url's(in simple language, if I select sth(href), then runs code with my function (id is id of div).

Comment: This part is crucial "id would need to be defined somewhere within the scope where the jQuery code is running". I would add also, that id can be defined as global variable and it would work (provided there's no variable `id` in any scope from where the code is run up to window object).

Comment: @WTK - A global variable counts as "somewhere in scope". But I'm still not clear what Gabriel is asking, even now that the code in the question has been updated - `id` isn't defined at all in the code we've been shown, but other than that I don't see anything wrong with the code Gabriel posted except the extra `});` at the end...

Comment: Agreed, he's question isn't clear, no doubt about that :)

Answer (score 0):

### THIS IS WRONG!!!

im not sure what you mean:

But try to change the order of your codes:

**THIS IS YOUR CODE AS IT IS NOW**

```
$(function (){    
    $( "#example").example({
        select: function ( event, ui){
            name(id);
        }
    });

    function name (id){
        document.getElementById(id);
    }
});
```

If the `select` method is triggers right away the `name` method isn't loaded to the memory,
 try:

```
$(function (){    
    function name (id){
        document.getElementById(id);
    }

    $( "#example").example({
        select: function ( event, ui){
            name(id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's incorrect. In JavaScript, function declarations are "hoisted", that is, they're treated as if they occurred at the beginning of their containing scope such that the two versions within your answer are equivalent. [Here's one of many articles about this](http://blog.caplin.com/2012/01/18/javascript-is-hard-part-2-the-hidden-world-of-hoisting/).

Comment: wow i didn't know.. Maybe because i always declare variables?? . thanks.

Comment: Yeah. If you declare your function as `var func = function() { }` the variable `func` itself gets hoisted with an undefined value, then the actual assignment happens at the point where your line of code is, so if you use that style you can't reference the functions until the lines after.